# How to use values of local variable in another function in C

Tags: c, variables, local

Suppose there are two function i.e., `function1()` and `function2()`

```
int function1()
{
  int F;
  printf("enter any value");
  scanf("%d",&F); 
  printf("Value is %d",F);
}
```

In `function1()` variable `F` is used which is local variable. How can I use the value of this local variable `F` in another function `function2()`?

Comment: anywhere in the program, outside main()

Comment: Which is the "mother" function and the "daughter" function - function1 or 2? Or are they sibling functions, both daughters to some other function (function3)?

Comment: this code is not compiling properly. (int function and no return)

Comment: Send it as a parameter or else use global variable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually, you already did.

passing the reference of `F` to `scanf` is how to use it.  Writing your own function, you only need to decide if you are passing the reference or the value.  If passing the value

```
int function(int value) {
 ...
}
```

which would be called like

```
function(F);
```

if passing the reference

```
int function(int* value) {
  ...
}
```

which would be called like

```
function(&F);
```

Answer (score 2):

Function local variable lifetimes are local to that function. If you have to use a value held by a local variable inside a function to another function, you can

1. `return` the value from `function1()`.
2. collect the return value in the caller function.
3. pass the stored value as argument to `function2()`.

<sup>NOTE: above answer assumes that both `function1()` and `function2()` are called from a parent function, maybe `func()`.</sup>

---

Edit:

if you need to use multiple values of local variables in other functions, (without using global variables), most common practice is to

1. pass a pointer to structure as argument of the `function1()`
2. fill the member element values inside `function1()` from the local variables.
3. pass the structure (or, address of the structure, is needed) again  to `function2()` as argument.

Answer (score 1):

define another function which accepts input and pass it to function2 like:

```
//main function
int f = function1();//return F from function1
function2(f);
```

Or if you can call function2 from function1, then you could do something like:

```
//function1
function2(F);
//function1 cond..
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can not do so explicitly because the scope and lifetime of local variables are limited to that function.

But if you want the variable of a F outside as well, the simplest possible solution is to make it global.

Secondly you can also pass F to another function as paramater.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible for function2 to use the local variable in function1 because the local variable is destroyed when the function1 returns. The solution is to return the value f as the result of function1.

```
int function1()
{
  int f;
  printf("enter any value");
  scanf("%d", &f); 
  printf("Value is %d", f);  
  return f;  // <-- return the value in local variable f
}


void function2(int f) // <-- pass f as argument to function 
{
   printf("Value is %d", f); // <-- use f inside function2
}


int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
   int f = function1();  // <-- store value returned by function1 in f 
   ...
   function2(f);  // <-- call function2 by passing f as argument
   ...
   function2(function1()); // <-- passing f directly from function1 to function2

   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create new `function2()` with passing by value of  --> `function2(F)`

Comment: Try to provide a code snippet, it will increase your chance to get an accepted answer.